# make shiny app standalone with user function

Tags: r, function, shiny

I have a shiny app with a bunch of user defined functions and dataframes being passed back and forth between them.

When run from RStudio, it works fine...I can see all the objects in the workspace and everything works just fine.  However, when I try to copy and paste the user defined functions in any configuration between the `ui.r` and `server.r` files, it complains about not being able to find objects and functions here and there.

What are the best practices for making a shiny app that stands alone, loads external csv files and handles user-defined functions?

Comment: If you have shared utility functions/data that you want in both the UI and Server, you could consider adding them to `global.R`, but keep in mind that `ui.R` runs once (at app load), then doesn't get re-executed. So any "dynamic" or reactive functions that you're trying to leverage from the UI won't work. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking...